# Call native function from managed code

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, wrapper

I'm trying to call native function from managed code in order to read a return value which I pass as array sbyte argument.
However, I cannot read any thing. The array sbyte is always the same and it isn't never modified by native function.

The following is the C++ function signature:

```
void __cdecl NativeFunction(int8_t StatusFlagOut[], int32_t *len);
```

and this other one is my C# Wrapper:

```
[DllImport("NativeDll.dll")]
internal static extern void NativeFunction([Out] sbyte[] statusFlagOut, ref int len);
```

Finally, this is the way I use to call function:

```
    sbyte[] output = null;
    int len = 0;
    NativeFunction(output, ref len); // while len is being filled properly, output never being changed.
```

Comment: How does your `NativeFunction` function look like? What does it do?

Comment: It is a simple test function and it has been build through LabView by my co-worker.

Comment: A possible problem is that arrays in C++ are passed as a pointer, and as all arguments it's passed by value (i.e. copied). So if there is an assignment to the pointer (e.g. `StatusFlagOut = new int8_t[...]`) then you only change the local copy of the pointer. However, without seeing the actual function it's impossible to answer this question, we can only guess (badly).

Answer (score 2):

The function is cdecl and so you need to specify that in the p/invoke:

```
[DllImport("NativeDll.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern void NativeFunction(
    [Out] sbyte[] statusFlagOut, 
    ref int len
);
```

The big problem is that you are not allocating memory for the native function to populate. It seems that you are expecting the native code to allocate the memory. That's clearly not how it has been designed, and rightly so. You always want caller to allocate memory for a host of reasons that I won't go in to here.

It looks like the native function is helpfully telling you how much to allocate. So it seems you can write the code like this:

```
int len = 0;
NativeFunction(null, ref len);
sbyte[] output = new sbyte[len];
NativeFunction(output, ref len);
```

Finally, a more general point. This is an interop question. They invariably require complete knowledge of both sides of the binary interop interface. You did not provide full details of the C++ side. You provided a function signature but did not provide the semantics of that function. So, I took an educated guess. It's really important to include these details, just in case our guesswork skills fail!

Answer (score 0):

When calling a native function with the `cdecl` calling convention, you should explicitly specify it:

```
[DllImport("NativeDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

If you don't, the CLR will by default interpret it as a `stdcall`, and expects the callee to clean the stack, where in the case of `cdecl`, the caller does, and bad stuff will happen.

As mentioned in the comments, `arrays` are kind of special when working with platform invokes, as they're passed by value. The following is described on MSDN on the `[Out]` page:

> For example, arrays passed by value, marshaled as In-only parameters
>   by default, can be changed to Out-only. However, the behavior does not
>   always provide expected semantics when the types include all-blittable
>   elements or fields because the interop marshaler uses pinning. If you
>   do not care about passing data into the callee, Out-only marshaling
>   can provide better performance for non-blittable types. Combining the
>   InAttribute and OutAttribute is particularly useful when applied to
>   arrays and formatted, non-blittable types. **Callers see the changes a
>   callee makes to these types only when you apply both attributes.** Since
>   these types require copying during marshaling, you can use InAttribute
>   and OutAttribute to reduce unnecessary copies.

Which means that your final signature should look like this:

```
    [DllImport("NativeDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal static extern void
        NativeFunction([In, Out] sbyte[] statusFlagOut, ref int len);
```

Comment: I don't believe that `[In, Out]` is correct here. The asker seems to want the data to flow from native to managed. But in any case `sbyte` is blittable. Which means that `InAttribute` and `OutAttribute` have no effect on the behaviour. That's what the quoted text in your answer explains.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Good point, though the documentation specifically mentions arrays *and* non-blittable types. Are you sure it's not relevant?

Comment: Arrays of blittable types are pinned. And `sbyte` is blittable. The real issue is that the managed code fails to allocate any memory.

Comment: @bit why don't you try a bit harder to give actionable information? Nothing works is no use. You still have not provided the info I described in my final paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved. You was right, there was a bug in native function.

However I also have to be add the calling convention specification like you suggeted me, so finally signature wrapper would appears like following:

```
[DllImport("NativeDll.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern void NativeFunction(
    [Out] sbyte[] statusFlagOut, 
    ref int len
);
```

Thank you very much.